# Reformatting date string

Tags: javascript, regex

Given input like `"Tue Aug 30 2011 11:47:14 GMT-0300"`, I would like output like `"MMM DD YYYY hh:mm"`.

What is an easy way to do it in JavaScript?

Comment: You don't need a regex to parse the date string, just ask the date object for the year, month, day, etc.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript) for more info.  Also, check out [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/).

Comment: `var output = "MMM DD YYYY hh:mm";` \*ducks\*

Comment: If I'm grabbing said date from a database like SharePoint, \*hits the dirt inside a premade Fallout vault* and it is in format yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss:SSSS, which of these solutions is going to work best?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via **JS**, you can try converting it to a date object and then extract the relevant bits and use them:

```
var d = new Date ("Tue Aug 30 2011 11:47:14 GMT-0300")
d.getMonth(); // gives you 7, so you need to translate that
```

To ease it off, you can use a library like [date-js](http://www.datejs.com/)

Via **regex**:

`/[a-zA-Z]{3} ([a-zA-Z]{3} \d{2} \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2})/` should do the trick.

```
var r = "Tue Aug 30 2011 11:47:14 GMT-0300".match(/^[a-zA-Z]{3} ([a-zA-Z]{3} \d{2} \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2})/);
alert(r[1]);   // gives you Aug 30 2011 11:47
```

Answer (score 2):

check out [`Date.parse`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp) which parses strings into UNIX timestamps and then you can format it as you like.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using a library, use [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/).  With Datejs, you can do:

```
new Date ("Tue Aug 30 2011 11:47:14 GMT-0300").toString('MMM dd yyyy hh:mm');
```

Answer (score 1):

A sample function:

```
function parseDate(d) {
    var m_names = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", 
                    "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", 
                    "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");

    var curr_day = d.getDate();
    var curr_hours = d.getHours();
    var curr_minutes = d.getMinutes();

    if (curr_day < 10) {
        curr_day = '0' + curr_day;
    }
    if (curr_hours < 10) {
        curr_hours = '0' + curr_hours;
    }
    if (curr_minutes < 10) {
        curr_minutes = '0' + curr_minutes;
    }

    return ( m_names[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + curr_day + ' ' + d.getFullYear() + ' ' + curr_hours + ':' + curr_minutes);
}


alert(parseDate(new Date()));
```

Or have a look at http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format for a more generic date formatting function