# Javascript reformat date string

Tags: javascript

I have this date fromat:

```
Mon Feb 02 2015 05:18:44 GMT+0000 (UTC)
```

How can I reformat it to something more friendlier such as `2/2/2015`
I am using javascript.

I tried using `.format` and `dateFormat` but they both return undefined value.

How can I do this?
I don't want to use any regex please.

Comment: Refer this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409299/how-to-get-current-formatted-date-dd-mm-yyyy-in-javascript-and-append-it-to-an-i

Comment: I already have the date, I just want to reformat it.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245176/reformatting-date-string

Comment: use this. var date = new Date('Mon Feb 02 2015 05:18:44 GMT+0000 (UTC)') to convert string to date

Comment: I've answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28038634/how-to-change-date-format-in-javascript/28038828#28038828

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want the simplest way just concat all of the separate parts

```
var output = dt.getMonth( ) + 1 +'/'+ dt.getDate( ) + '/' +dt.getFullYear( );
```

There are a few libraries that will handle more advanced stuff if you need it, but that is the lightest way I can think of doing what you are asking.

Answer (score 5):

Use this awesome library. [Moment JS](http://momentjs.com/)

For your case it would be some thing link

```
var dateString = 'Mon Feb 02 2015 05:18:44 GMT+0000';
var date = new Moment(dateString);

alert(date.format('MM/dd/YYYY'));
```

Answer (score 4):

`var d = new Date();
var n = d.toLocaleDateString();`

I think this will give you desired output.

Comment: The result of *toLocaleString* is entirely implementation dependent and gives different results in different browsers. So while some might give the required format, others will not.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass it to `Date` Object:

```
var dateString = "Mon Feb 02 2015 05:18:44 GMT+0000 (UTC)";
var date = new Date(dateString);

date.getDate(); // > 2 (the day number)
date.getMonth(); // > 1 (the month number as 0 is January, 11 is December)
```

You can also find a lib to do the format job or format yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to parse and re-format a date. Here is a very simple method that works for your date format:

```
var d = 'Mon Feb 02 2015 05:18:44 GMT+0000 (UTC)';
var dStr = new Date(d).toDateString();
```

The value of `dSTr` will be something like 'Sun Feb 01 2015'.