# How to format the date in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, date, format

I retrieve the data from MongoDB,and it contains date, but the date is String format.
I'm trying to use following codes to format the date:

```
var str = data.date;// assume that is 2002/2/2
var date = new Date(str);
console.log(date);
```

However the output is :Sat Feb 02 2002 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AEDT)
How can I make the output become the YYYY/MM/DD?
Many thanks .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format date in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392328/how-to-format-date-in-angularjs)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28271904/2460773 . consider using a js libary such as momentJS http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use a **date filter** do that in your **HTML Template:**

```
{{date | date: 'YYYY/MM/DD'}}
```

Change your **controller** code to:

```
var str = data.date;
$scope.date = new Date(str);
```

so that 'date' can be binded to the HTML template as explained.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the output is YYYY/02/DD  only the month is correct.

Comment: Oh thanks this problem is solved, I'm using yyyy/MM/dd